# Why is $PATH different in the Nautilus-Elementary embedded terminal?

Tags: nautilus, command-line, nautilus-elementary, environment-variables, paths

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with Nautilus-Elementary installed. When I open the embedded terminal in Nautilus (F7) and run `echo $PATH`, I get:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:./usr/local/bin:/bin
```

When run the same command in the regular terminal, I get:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Is there some logic in this behavior, is this a bug, or did I just forget to configure something?

Comment: That is interesting, a freshly-configured `nautilus-terminal` works for me - `$PATH` matches perfectly. Maybe your `.bashrc` or `.profile` do something tricky?

Comment: I freshly installed Ubuntu 10.10 on an old laptop this morning and added nautilus-elementary. I didn't alter .bashrc or .profile as far as I know. I guess nautilus-elementary is not identical to the embedded terminal shipped with nautilus-elementary - but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Like all terminals launched in gnome, it should be inheriting the PATH environment from the parent process. These ultimately come from the `/etc/login.defs` and `/etc/environment` files and are initialised when ever you login.

In fact if you go to another tty and log in (Ctrl+Alt+F1) you'll see the same path as gnome terminal. But not the same limited path as elementary.

I'd ask you to report a bug, but the elementary team hasn't registered a bug reporting service.

Comment: Thanks Martin. In fact, I did file a bug 2 weeks ago at https://bugs.launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+bug/675807 but there hasn't been a reaction yet.

Comment: But wait, I now see that a day after filing that bug, the project was abandoned: https://launchpad.net/nautilus-elementary/+announcement/7221.

Comment: They probably wanted to fork completely. Please mark the question as answered :-)